# Search word not found in a vector?

Tags: c++, words

I'm implementing a function where the user can search for a word in a vector. The only problem is, my search function is only finding certain words and I'm not sure why.

```
 ifstream in("testdata.txt");
string word1;
vector<string> individual_words;
while (in >> word1)
{
    individual_words.push_back(word1);
}
```

**Inside the file testdata.txt is:**

```
Hello how are you
Good are you well?
Snazzy piece of toast
```

Here is the code where I compare the two words.

```
string search_word;

 while (cin >> search_word)
    {

        for (int f=0; f < individual_words.size(); f ++)
        {
            cout << "individual words: " << individual_words[f] <<endl;
            cout << "search word: " << search_word;
            if (search_word == individual_words[f])
            {
                cout << " FOUND THE SAME WORD\n!";
                break;
            }


        }
}
```

For some reason it's only catching certain words in a .txt file and I'm not exactly sure why. I've looked at it and it looks like it ignores the first word and it ignores every last word on each sentence.

Comment: Continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19350506/1168156 ?

Comment: I was unable to get the vector iterator to work on my code. I feel that I'm very close to being able to get the right search_word, but I don't understand why it's only able to pick up on about half of the words I type in. Any ideas?

Comment: what kind value are you trying to search? how do you expect individual_words holding the value?

Comment: individual_words is holding a string name. so it will individual_words[1] = "Hello", individual_words[2] = "how", etc. I just don't understand why if search_word is "Hello" it's not saying they are equal

Answer (score 0):

Your vector will have duplicates, so it will only find the first occurrences of the words "are" and "you" before your loop breaks.  Logically, there is nothing else wrong in this section of code, though it would be better written as:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    // simplified for demonstration purposes
    string test = "Hello how are you\nGood are you well?\nSnazzy piece of toast";
    istringstream iss(test);
    vector<string> words;
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(words));

    string search_word;
    while (cin >> search_word)
    {
        // this works, but is unnecessary
        /*for (int f=0; f < words.size(); f ++)
        {
            cout << "individual words: " << words[f] <<endl;
            cout << "search word: " << search_word;
            if (search_word == words[f])
            {
                cout << " FOUND THE SAME WORD\n!";
                break;
            }
        }*/

        // this is a better approach
        vector<string>::iterator it = find(words.begin(), words.end(), search_word);
        if (it != words.end())
        {
            cout << "Found the word:  " << *it << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Not found!" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I want to open any file such as my "testdata.txt" file, would I just make string test = "testdata.txt". (I have no idea if that is even possible) EDIT: To rephrase my question, how can I make string test know what the contents of the file are?

Comment: That part of your code is fine.  I just used a string stream to simplify the test to where you are actually having the problem.